# How to use python list to group elements and average the group numbers?

Tags: python

How to use python list to group elements and average the group numbers?
I have a list [1_1 34 1_1 45 1_1 78 2_1 33 2_1 12 3_2 78 3_1 90 1_3 65 1_2 98 1_3 62 1_3 54 1_3 48 1_3 28 1_2 21 1_2 35] the first element is a group name and second element is a number.
how can I put them in a grouping such [1_1 34 1_1 45 1_1 78 1_2 21 1_2 35 1_3 62.....]
then average by grouping, such [1_1 52.3 1_2 28 1_3 34 .......]

thank you

OK, let me clarify a little about this. I had a test result looks like this and I want to use python to group them and show the average on each group. thank you.

1_1     32
1_1     13
1_1     13
1_1     31
1_3     13
1_1     35
1_2     41
1_1     19
1_2     64
1_3     23
1_2     23
1_2     22
1_2     67
1_2     41
1_3     40
1_1     35
1_2     20
1_2     35
1_3     69
1_2     67
1_3     68
1_1     21
1_3     70
1_3     23
1_3     47
1_3     38
1_3     67
1_3     13
1_2     13
1_2     22
1_3     22
1_3     35
1_3     14
1_3     68
1_2     67
1_3     65
1_3     13
1_3     41
1_3     67
1_3     22
1_3     67
1_2     22
1_2     42
1_2     13
1_3     66
1_3     68
1_3     67
1_2     66
1_3     13
1_3     68
1_2     39

Comment: what you've tried so far?

Comment: you could use dictionary and them find the average according to each key.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a code writing service

Comment: I used FujiApple's but got an errorTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "results.py", line 34, in <module>
    print {a: sum(b) / float(len(b)) for a, b in grouped.iteritems()}
  File "results.py", line 34, in <dictcomp>
    print {a: sum(b) / float(len(b)) for a, b in grouped.iteritems()}
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Sorry, I am doing a project and learning python. It can be done on MS spreadsheet sorting then and get the average, but I am exploring the python solution. if you think this is providing me a code writing service, please don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets say

```
indexes=['1_1','1_1','1_1','2_1','2_1','3_2','3_1','1_3','1_2','1_3','1_3','1_3','1_3','1_2','1_2']
values=[34,45,78,33,12,78,90,65,98,62,54,48,28,21,35]
```

grouping is fun with pandas

```
import pandas as pd
```

create a dataframe with index and values

```
df=pd.DataFrame(values,columns=["values"],index=indexes)
```

now groupby the index and do mean

```
df.groupby(df.index).mean()
```

result looks like:

```
        values
1_1     52.333333
1_2     51.333333 
1_3     51.400000
2_1     22.500000
3_1     90.000000
3_2     78.000000
```

Comment: Well, this very helpful. I out put it to a csv file by adding df.groupby(df.index).mean().to_csv("/home/jim/test.csv", sep=','). it is working thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand the question correctly then the below code should give you what you need and is fairly pythonic.  I've made the assumption that the 'key' is a string (i.e. `"1_1"`) and the value is an integer.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

theList = ["1_1", 34, "1_1", 45, "1_1", 78, "2_1", 33, "2_1", 12, "3_2", 78, "3_1", 90, "1_3", 65, "1_2", 98, "1_3", 62, "1_3", 54, "1_3", 48, "1_3", 28, "1_2", 21, "1_2", 35]

paired = sorted(zip(theList[::2], theList[1::2]), key=itemgetter(0))
grouped = {a: [q[1] for q in b] for a, b in groupby(paired, key=itemgetter(0))}
print {a: sum(b) / float(len(b)) for a, b in grouped.iteritems()}
```

Produces:

```
{'3_1': 90.0, '3_2': 78.0, '2_1': 22.5, '1_3': 51.4, '1_2': 51.333333333333336, '1_1': 52.333333333333336}
```

This works by first zipping the original list into a new list of tuples of 2 elements (i'th and i+1'th paired together) then sorting them by the 1st element of the tuple pair which gives:

```
[('1_1', 34), ('1_1', 45), ('1_1', 78), ('1_2', 98), ('1_2', 21), ('1_2', 35), ('1_3', 65), ('1_3', 62), ('1_3', 54), ('1_3', 48), ('1_3', 28), ('2_1', 33), ('2_1', 12), ('3_1', 90), ('3_2', 78)]
```

Then it groups these by the 1st element of the tuple pair and forms a list of the 2nd element which gives:

```
{'3_1': [90], '3_2': [78], '2_1': [33, 12], '1_3': [65, 62, 54, 48, 28], '1_2': [98, 21, 35], '1_1': [34, 45, 78]}
```

Finally it just displayed the average for the items in the list for each key giving the final result.

Answer (score 0):

Here's two possible approaches to sort and store them in a way that makes all future manipulations possible:

**EITHER** a list of tuples, where the first item is the group name and the second item is the element. This approach has the advantage of allowing a "general sort" of all items. To get there from the basic list to this list of tuples do this:

```
initial_list = ['1_1', 12, '1_2', 23....]
tuple_list = [(initial_list[i], initial_list[i + 1]) for i in xrange(0, len(initial_list), 2)]
```

**OR** a dictionary with lists, where the keys are the group names and the values are lists with the elements. This approach is more flexible if you want to do stats (sums, averages, etc) on the values of a group:

```
initial_list = ['1_1', 12, '1_2', 23....]
dict_with_lists = {}
for i in xrange(0, len(initial_list), 2):
    group_name = initial_list[i]
    if group_name in dict_with_lists:
        dict_with_lists[group_name].append(initial_list[i + 1])
    else:
        dict_with_lists[group_name] = [initial_list[i + 1]]
```

Comment: @PM2Ring care to pinpoint what exactly is not working for you? (apart from the obvious elipsis left in the initial_list)

Comment: Oops! I forgot that underscore is now legal in numbers. Sorry about that.

Comment: @PM2Ring well, you are quite right actually and it makes sense to edit it this way (python 3.6 is really not that well spread)